# Equivalence of two cyclic codes

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

I'm trying to solve the following, but have no clue:

> Let $$\sigma: \{0, \ldots, n-1\} \rightarrow \{0,\ldots,n-1 \}$$ $$x \mapsto x+a \text{ mod} n$$  a permutation with $(a,n)=1$. Assume to have  $\mathcal{C}$ cyclic code of length $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.
>
> Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) = \{(c_{\sigma(0),\ldots,c_\sigma(n-1)}) | (c_0,\ldots,c_{n-1}) \in \mathcal{C} \}$ **is a cyclic code equivalent to $\mathcal{C}$**

---

Of course it's equivalent because is just a permutation of the components of the code $\mathcal{C}$. That's precisely the definition of equivalent codes.

The problem is in the cyclic structure: I'd like to show that if I take a vector in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$, then its shifting by one position towards right is again in $\sigma(C)$.  I need to use the specific structure of $\sigma$ and the fact that $C$ is cyclic, but I really can't figure out how to move.

Comment: Doesn't $\sigma$ amount to cyclically shifting $a$ positions (or $-a$, depending on which direction you define to be *shift $1$ position*)?  That operation commutes with the cyclic shift by $1$ position. Or, viewed differently $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: In other words, the condition $\gcd(a,n)=1$ is unnecessary. The question would be more interesting, if we had $\sigma: x\mapsto ax$. A) Then we need the condition on gcd's, and B) when we cyclically shift a codeword by 1 position, the image is shifted by $a^{-1}$ positions, no?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks, I can't understand the folllowing point you wrote: " That operation commutes with the cyclic shift by 1 position". How can I prove it?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry, but I still can't figure out the point to solve the exercise. I mean, it's clear to me that $\sigma$ commutes with the shift of one position to the right. Said that, why is it cyclic? I saw that if is cyclic, than the shift of one position is still in the code, but here I'm shifting of $a$ positions!

Comment: If $\tau$ is the shift by one position, then we have, for all words $c\in\mathcal{C}$ that also $\tau(c)\in\mathcal{C}$. Therefore 
$$\sigma(c)=\tau(\tau(\cdots \tau(c)))\in\mathcal{C}.$$ There are $a$ copies of $\tau$ in there. The commuting I mentioned is not really needed, but it does imply that
$$\sigma(\tau(c))=\tau(\sigma(c)).$$
Therefore
$$\tau(\sigma/\mathcal{C}))=\sigma(\tau(\mathcal{C})=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$$
implying that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is stable under $\tau$, i.e. cyclic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks, it's more clear to me now :) Just one last word:  equivalence is trivial, because in practice what happens is that I just change the exponents of $c$ (thinking at it in poly form)